# Most cost effective package combination (shipping)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, calculation

I have a very simple function for my shipping method to put the packages together. Basically everything works exactly the way it should. However, in special constellations, e.g. when the quantity is 42, more costs are charged than necessary.

The variable `$packages` is filled like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 18er
            [contain] => 18
            [cost] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 12er
            [contain] => 12
            [cost] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 6er
            [contain] => 6
            [cost] => 8
        )

)
```

The relevant part of my function is the following:

```
$overrun    = 42; // Items in cart
$cost       = 0;
$filled     = array();
$quantities = array();
foreach( $packages as $the_package ){
    $delivers = floor( $overrun / $the_package['contain'] );
    if( ! $delivers ) {
        continue;
    }
    $filled[$the_package['name']] = $delivers;
    $overrun = $overrun - ( $delivers * $the_package['contain'] );
    $cost = $cost + ( $delivers * $the_package['cost'] );
}
```

After the calculation, the variable `$filled` is defined as follows, which results in shipping costs of $18:

```
Array
(
    [18er] => 2
    [6er] => 1
)
```

Optimal would be a result of $15, therefore the variable `$filled` would have to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [18er] => 1
    [12er] => 2
)
```

I guess I can't do it at all with this simple foreach loop. Can you give me some help on how to solve this?

You can find a working example at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uoILt).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are right that this optimization problem requires more sophisticated solution if you really need the best possible result. If you are able to define the function mathematically you will be able to find the derivative numerically - or you may choose to try the popular AMPL math package (https://ampl.com/try-ampl/download-a-free-demo/) From its bundled solvers I would recommend the MINOS one.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thank you for your comment. The AMPL package looks very promising on the first sight. Unfortunately there may be a licence issue. The code I'm struggling with is for a WooCommerce plugin. I thought this information is useless in my question, but in case of 3rd party packages relevant though.

Comment: You are right that the free size-limited version (the one I am referring to) indeed is marked/intended for noncommercial use. If you intend to sell your code - there will be a licensing issue. The only other option you have (besides buying AMPL license) is to write down your math function, find its derivative(s) on paper - and then choose how to find the global minimum programmaticaly. Or, you may try searching some open-source solver ...

Comment: It's not clear what the business rules require use of 6er box; even for qty 1 the 12er is the cheaper choice.  If you require qty <=6 to use the 6er box b/c that's the rule, then do so.  This suggests for any qty > 6 to never use the 6er box if you want the lowest shipping charges.

Answer (score 2):

Half of my answers comes from [this question and the subsequent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4632322/231316), so if my answer works, please vote over there, too. I'll start with a tweaked version of that code here. The gist of it is that it takes each item in a given array `$numbers` such as `[6, 12, 18]` and sees if it can sum up to `$target` such as `42`. My tweak to this function is that I'm also passing in a `$final` array so that I can get something back instead of just printing.

```php
function subset_sum(array &$final, array $numbers, int $target, array $partial = []): void
{
    $s = array_sum($partial);

    if ($s === $target) {
        if (!in_array($partial, $final, true)) {
            $final[] = $partial;
        }
    }

    if ($s >= $target) {
        return;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
        $n = $numbers[$i];
        $remaining = array_slice($numbers, $i + 1);
        subset_sum($final, $remaining, $target, array_merge($partial, [$n]));
    }
}
```

The problem with that function, however, is that it tries every combination of the array provided, but once a number is used it won't try it again in the same sequence. So in your case, that function would never try `18 + 18 + 6` because `18` isn't in the array *twice*. To fix that, we'll use `array_fill` to repeat our numbers as much as needed. For instance, we need `6` to be in the array seven times to target `42`.

```php
function grow_initial_array(array $numbers, int $max): array
{
    $numbers = array_unique($numbers);
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        assert(is_int($n));
        // The maximum number of times that $n can be divided into $max
        $x = (int)floor($max / $n);
        // Fill our array with that many items (repeat 6 seven times for 42)
        $f = array_fill(1, $x, $n);
        $ret = array_merge($ret, $f);
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

For your three inputs of `[18, 12, 6]` this produces an array of :

```php
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 12
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 6
    [9] => 6
    [10] => 6
    [11] => 6
)
```

Next up, we need to merge this simple data back in with your business logic. There's lots of ways to do this including the `array_reduce` etc. functions, but I'm just going to keep it simple with nested `foreach` loops which might not be as performant/pretty. This code creates a new array with keys being the sum of package options. The values for those sums is another array of potential options (just in case two or more combinations sum up to the same total). The third inner array is an array of your product options as initially outlined.

```php
function remerge_to_packages_with_sums(array $final, array $packages): array
{
    $package_options = [];
    foreach ($final as $numbers) {
        $package_option = [];
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($numbers as $n) {
            foreach ($packages as $p) {
                if ($p['contain'] === $n) {
                    $package_option[] = $p;
                    $sum += $p['cost'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($sum, $package_options)) {
            $package_options[$sum] = [];
        }

        $package_options[$sum][] = $package_option;

    }

    return $package_options;
}
```

That code produces the following array (only the first key is shown):

```php
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 18er
                            [contain] => 18
                            [cost] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 18er
                            [contain] => 18
                            [cost] => 5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => 6er
                            [contain] => 6
                            [cost] => 8
                        )

                )

        )
        // Extra items removed for display purposes
    )
)
```

You can pretty much stop there if you want, your answer lies in the deeply nested array. But if you want to keep going, you can transform that into a smaller array where the keys are the sum, and the values are arrays of arrays matching your initial input:

```php
function reduce_merged_array(array $merged_array): array
{
    $final = [];
    foreach ($merged_array as $sum => $package_collection) {
        if (!array_key_exists($sum, $final)) {
            $final[$sum] = [];
        }
        foreach ($package_collection as $pc) {
            $local = [];
            foreach ($pc as $item) {
                if (!array_key_exists($item['name'], $local)) {
                    $local[$item['name']] = 0;
                }
                $local[$item['name']]++;
            }
            $final[$sum][] = $local;
        }
    }

    return $final;
}
```

Which produces:

```php
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [18er] => 1
                    [12er] => 2
                )

        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [18er] => 2
                    [6er] => 1
                )

        )
    // Only two shown for example
)
```

We can put those functions to work with this code, the in-code comments should hopefully explain everything:

```php
// Initial array
$packages = [
    [
        'name' => '18er',
        'contain' => 18,
        'cost' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'name' => '12er',
        'contain' => 12,
        'cost' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'name' => '6er',
        'contain' => 6,
        'cost' => 8,
    ],
];

// Get just our contain values
$values = array_column($packages, 'contain');

// This is our quantity that we are targeting
$target = 42;

// Will hold the result of potential summing options
$sum_options = [];

// Duplicate our items in values so that we can get every possible combination
$value_duplicated = grow_initial_array($values, $target);

// Calculate all possible sums
subset_sum($sum_options, $value_duplicated, $target);

if (0 === count($sum_options)) {
    // TODO: Nothing found that matches
    exit;
}

// Convert back to packages
$packages_with_sums = remerge_to_packages_with_sums($sum_options, $packages);

// Convert to simplified array
$reduced = reduce_merged_array($packages_with_sums);

// Sort by sum, smallest first
ksort($reduced);

// Best options
$best_price = array_key_first($reduced);
$best_priced_options = reset($reduced);

// Worst options
$worst_price = array_key_last($reduced);
$worst_priced_options = end($reduced);
```

The `$best_priced_options` and `$worst_priced_options` variables are arrays, just FYI, because it could be possible for two or more combinations to sum up to a given price.

Comment: Hey @ChrisHaas , thank you very much for this detailed answer and the fair handling of the origins. I will need some time to unpack everything.